# Swapping two pages in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

What is the easiest way to swap two pages in Adobe Acrobat ?

*(for example, page 15 is on page 16 and vice versa ... how to put them proper  ?)*

Comment: @Stephen Jennings - Why did you put the Acrobat in the title ? You already have it in the tags.

Comment: I felt "swapping two pages" wasn't a good description of what you wanted to do. You can attract more people to read and answer questions with more specific titles.  Tags are for categorization, but you still want the question title to describe what you want answered.

Comment: @Stephen Jennings - How would you better describe this operation than "swapping" then ?

Comment: @Idigas "Swapping" is an appropriate word, but I was trying to help you to get better answers by specifying what product you were referring to. If you feel that strongly that it doesn't belong there, feel free to edit it out again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Acrobat (not Acrobat Reader) you can drag and drop the page thumbnails to reorganise them.

Comment: Hmpf .. figures! Had to be something simple and obvious. Just had to ... Thanks Mike ! p.s. Did I mention "Reader" somewhere ?

Comment: @ldigas: no, but the caveat might be beneficial to other readers. adobe hasn't been consistent with their naming -- it's now "Adobe Reader" but used to be "Adobe Acrobat Reader".